# Why "docker build" fails on local image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Probably I'm missing something obvious, but could someone please explain the following:

When I pull and run an image, e.g `docker pull dgraziotin/lamp && docker run -t -i -p 80:80 -p 3306:3306 --name osxlamp dgraziotin/lamp` - it works just fine

Now I want to play with Dockerfile and build it manually on my computer (I can do this, right?)

So I download the source files from Github https://github.com/dgraziotin/osx-docker-lamp, `cd` to unpacked folder and run `docker build -t test .`

The building process starts but I see lot of weird errors like "Package php5-mysql is not available". I tried different images with the same result. How to properly build local images?

UPD:

Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:latest
MAINTAINER Daniel Graziotin <daniel@ineed.coffee>
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2016-03-29

# based on tutumcloud/tutum-docker-lamp
# MAINTAINER Fernando Mayo <fernando@tutum.co>, Feng Honglin <hfeng@tutum.co>

ENV DOCKER_USER_ID 501 
ENV DOCKER_USER_GID 20

ENV BOOT2DOCKER_ID 1000
ENV BOOT2DOCKER_GID 50

# Tweaks to give Apache/PHP write permissions to the app
RUN usermod -u ${BOOT2DOCKER_ID} www-data && \
    usermod -G staff www-data && \
    useradd -r mysql && \
    usermod -G staff mysql

RUN groupmod -g $(($BOOT2DOCKER_GID + 10000)) $(getent group $BOOT2DOCKER_GID | cut -d: -f1)
RUN groupmod -g ${BOOT2DOCKER_GID} staff

# Install packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install supervisor wget git apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql pwgen php-apc php5-mcrypt zip unzip  && \
  echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# needed for phpMyAdmin
run php5enmod mcrypt

# Add image configuration and scripts
ADD start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD start-mysqld.sh /start-mysqld.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
ADD supervisord-apache2.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf
ADD supervisord-mysqld.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf

# Remove pre-installed database
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

# Add MySQL utils
ADD create_mysql_users.sh /create_mysql_users.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

# Add phpmyadmin
RUN wget -O /tmp/phpmyadmin.tar.gz https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.0/phpMyAdmin-4.6.0-all-languages.tar.gz
RUN tar xfvz /tmp/phpmyadmin.tar.gz -C /var/www
RUN ln -s /var/www/phpMyAdmin-4.6.0-all-languages /var/www/phpmyadmin
RUN mv /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

ENV MYSQL_PASS:-$(pwgen -s 12 1)
# config to enable .htaccess
ADD apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Configure /app folder with sample app
RUN mkdir -p /app && rm -fr /var/www/html && ln -s /app /var/www/html
ADD app/ /app

#Environment variables to configure php
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 10M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 10M

# Add volumes for the app and MySql
VOLUME  ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql", "/app" ]

EXPOSE 80 3306
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

SOLVED As I understood many of custom images contain outdated/invalid code and must be avoided as much as possible. We should rely on official well known and supported images.

Comment: You did everything right. I tried this repo and get the same errors. This repo is just too old and some packages might be removed or renamed. Try to play with this [janes/alpine-lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/janes/alpine-lamp/) (there is the GitHub link as well), I just tested it.

Comment: and to add to the previous comment, if u really want this specific image to work, try changing php5 instances to php56 or php7.  i believe this is because of php 7 rollout some package names changed. or add to the container\s apt a repo where php5 is still served

Comment: @zstate Just tried to build :) "ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  php5-xdebug (missing):
    required by: world[php5-xdebug]
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories &&     apk update &&     apk add .... returned a non-zero code: 1
"

Comment: @ymakux sorry I meant to give you this link [greyltc/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/greyltc/lamp/) which I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to the exact problem, but your Dockerfile could use some rework based on [Best Practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

I'd like to point out the ADD vs COPY best practice and the [deprecated MAINTAINER Instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) (you should use LABEL maintainer="Daniel Graziotin ").

Also on the part where you add phpmyadmin it's useless to use RUN instead of ADD if you don't extract and delete the archive in the same layer (using multiline arguments). This can also be found under the ADD vs COPY best practices.

Other than that I can say this is a pretty solid Dockerfile! Sad it won't work because of the application...